# Best practices for joining tables and notifying ContentObservers in Android ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a ContentProvider which handles all the data insertion and retrieval related to my application, I'm following the pattern suggested by Virgil Dobjanschi on Google I/O. I am using the first pattern.

My problem is that I have a logical entity that was represented by multiple tables in the database.

For example, I have an Articles table and an ArticleExtras table. Articles represents the article itself, while ArticleExtras represents addtional information about certain Article, like number of comments.

I used CursorAdapter in the UI to display the Article title and the number of comments of that Article in one row of ListView.

To implement that, I added a `left outer join ArticleExtras on` statement in my ContentProvider query method for Article table, in order for CursorAdapter to get ArticleExtras along with the Article itself.

When new Articles are fetched from the web, I insert it into the database via ContentProvider, and then the CursorAdapter got notified and update the UI, this part worked as expected.

But when I fetched the number of comments  (ArticleExtras), I want the same CursorAdapter, which is watching for changes in the `content://com.myapp.content/Articles`, to be notified, too, so I can update my row in the ListView.

My current implementation is like this: After inserting ArticleExtras into the database, I start a new query to check if Articles table has any rows that is related to the ArticleExtras I just inserted. If so I'll make a new uri for that Article( for example: `content://com.myapp.cotent/Articles/123`), and call `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)`, so the corresponding CursorAdapter that is watching for changes of this Article will get notified.

Is the approach correct, or is there any better way to implement what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout [ContactsProvider2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java), in it they set the notification uri to the `AUTHORITY_URI` which appears to be a catch all for the other URIs in the provider. I had the same probem and I have tried this myself for a provider with multiple tables and joins on those tables, and it works fine.